# Gracefully stop rufus scheduler on heroku worker

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, signals, rufus-scheduler

I run rufus-scheduler in a rake task that runs on a heroku worker. I get regularly SIGTERM exception, because of regular heroku dynos restart (see the [heroku dyno docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm)). I'd like to implement graceful shutdown shown in the docs mentioned above and shutdown rufus scheduler during this process:

```
trap('TERM') do
  scheduler.shutdown(:kill)
  exit
end
```

However when I try to send SIGTERM to the process with this task, I get error:

```
can't be called from trap context
```

Is there any method to gracefully shutdown rufus scheduler on SIGTERM?
I use ruby 2.0, rake 10.0.4, rufus-scheduler 3.0.2.

P.S. No, I can't use heroku scheduler, because I need to run this task every minute ;-).

**EDIT** (jmettraux)

test code: https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/a4c00374f58e9f7affa8

Ruby 2.0.0-p247, rufus-scheduler 3.0.5 on Debian GNU/Linux yields:

```
/home/jmettraux/w/rufus-scheduler/lib/rufus/scheduler/job_array.rb:74:
  in `synchronize': can't be called from trap context (ThreadError)
    from /home/jmettraux/w/rufus-scheduler/lib/rufus/scheduler/job_array.rb:74:in `to_a'
    from /home/jmettraux/w/rufus-scheduler/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:276:in `jobs'
    from /home/jmettraux/w/rufus-scheduler/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:127:in `shutdown'
    from t.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
    from t.rb:18:in `call'
    from t.rb:18:in `sleep'
    from t.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

Same platform, but with Ruby 1.9.3-p392 and it gracefully shuts down.

Comment: Please include the complete error message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4411227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's Ruby 2.0 specific (https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4411227)

The next version of rufus-scheduler will include a workaround.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/98

Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: rufus-scheduler 3.0.6 released. It includes the fix.

https://rubygems.org/gems/rufus-scheduler

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is due to `Thread` synchronization in `trap`. I would work around it this way:

```
p "#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"
p $$
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

trap('TERM') do
  $quit = true
end

s.every '10s' do
  p :hello
end

s.every '1s' do
  if $quit
    p :bye
    s.shutdown(:kill)
  end
end

s.join
```

shell1:

```
$ ruby exit_scheduler.rb
"2.0.0-p0"
60580
```

shell2:

```
$ kill -s TERM 60580
```

shell1:

```
:bye
```